# Siebel State Model

Tags: siebel

My requirement is to restrict some picklist values based on the user login. 
Ex: If the organization of the logged in user is, 'AAA', it should show all the values, if the organization is 'BBB', it should show only values X and y.

I have used the state model in order to achieve the above requirement.
I have created transitions, and marked public on some transitions and removed the public on other transitions and defined the authorized users for them.

Without defining users, first I have tried to add a rule for a certain transition,

ex: Organization = 'BBB'

But it's not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

State model condition changes are reflected only after object manager restart. Did you try restarting your server and then trying?